# JQuery has (mostly) stopped working on Rails -- is the asset pipeline to blame?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, asset-pipeline

Following [the Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) I had DataTables, a JQuery plug-in, working just fine in my Rails 3.2.9 app.

Then it suddenly stopped working. (That is, the tables now just render as plain HTML.) And I don't know what change caused the breakage and I can't work out what's happening.) Can you?

JQuery seems to be loading OK, as this script, which I store in `/app/assets/javascripts/nospam.js`, is doing exactly what it's meant to do on the same page that DataTables is failing:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#my-email').html(function(){
    var e = "steven";
    var a = "@";
    var d = "testivate";
    var c = ".com";
    var h = 'mailto:' + e + a + d + c;
    $(this).parent('a').attr('href', h);
    return e + a + d + c;
  });
});
```

When I load the page in Chrome and go to View > Developer > JavaScript Console > Console, I see an `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'` error connecting to the line with the `return` in this included script:

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
    return $('#areas').dataTable({
      bJQueryUI: true
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

The asset pipeline seems to be loading all the right files, as it generates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testivate</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="/assets/html5shiv-printshiv.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/areas.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/assignments.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/categories.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/heuristics.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery.placeholder.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/nospam.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/reports.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/dataTables/src/demo_table_jui.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/_base.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/ie.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/ie6.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/print.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/screen.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="Rss5Hf9sPcQQQRViXgEUfSxvYEshBukjV96gM5+cEYc=" name="csrf-token" />
    <meta content='jq8ezzUss-fo-h7ml8zmwSvdpmzJlbE6VjN7Dphcnp8' name='google-site-verification'>
  </head>
```

Selected code from other relevant files...

**/app/assets/javascripts/application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/areas.js.coffee**:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#areas').dataTable
    bJQueryUI: true
```

**/app/views/areas/index.html.haml**:

```
%table.display#areas
  %thead
    %tr
      %td Foo
      %td Bar
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td Foo
      %td Bar
```

**Gemfile**:

```
gem "compass"
gem "sass"
gem "sass-rails"
gem "haml"
gem "haml-rails"
gem "susy"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "html5shiv-rails"
gem "normalize-rails"

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails"
  gem "coffee-rails"
  gem "compass-rails"
  gem "compass-susy-plugin"
  gem "fancy-buttons"
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
  gem "jquery-ui-rails"
  gem "uglifier"
end
```

**/config/application.rb**:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
end

module Testivate
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

**/config/environments/development.rb**:

```
Testivate::Application.configure do
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same developer tools in Chrome. Click on Network and check that /assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1 is loading.

Comment: Initially the Network tab was empty. When I hit refresh, a list of downloads appeared. In the "jquery.dataTables.js" row it says: Method: GET; Status: 304/Not Modified; Type: Application/JavaScript; Initiator: Reports 8 / Parser; Size: 252B; Time: 596ms

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed with the asset pipeline. It was loading two copies of JQuery because I'd precompiled the assets to push them to production, but the precompiled versions were hanging around locally and being served alongside the dynamically compiled versions. Now to work out how to stop that happening...

Comment: And the answer is there no need to precompile your assets locally before pushing to Heroku as if you don't, Heroku will attempt to precompile them for you on the server when generating slugs. Nice.